# Block wise processing of an image in matlab

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

I have an image of size 256*256 and I want block wise processing of that image. To do that I want to get 64*64=4096 blocks, each of 16 pixels. I'm new to Matlab so I found it hard to find specific commands to do that. So far what I have is,

```
    I=imread('kidneyimage.jpg');
    I=rgb2gray(I);
    % block wise processing needed.
```

Any help with the commands is really appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

To do that you can use the function `im2col`.

http://www.mathworks.fr/help/toolbox/images/ref/im2col.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Actually what I want is to do the haar wavelet transform for each block and get the features [Ca,Ch,Cv,Cd]. I know the command for haar transform [Ca,Ch,Cv,Cd] = dwt2(I,'haar'); But how can I pass blocks instead of the whole image and get [Ca,Ch,Cv,Cd] for each block seperately?

Answer (score 1):

If you've just started using Matlab, try the simplest way: use two nested [`for`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/learn_matlab/f4-1931.html) loops to iterate over and manipulate every block. Check out the help page of [`imread`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/imread.html), this function gives you a matrix filled with the color of every pixel. Matlab has special notation to extract parts of matrices using the [colon (:) operator](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/colon.html), so you can easily modify blocks of the image one-by-one.

Comment: I would actually recommend for anyone (especially beginners) to get accustomed to solving problems _without_ `for` loops, and doing it the right way.

Comment: @EitanT As far as I have heard, for loops in Matlab is a performance issue. Is that correct?

Comment: @Krishan yes, in MATLAB you should always try to do without them.

Comment: @Krishan From a performance point of view, using Matlab instead of C/C++ is a performance issue :) If your code must be really fast, use Matlab only for creating a draft solution, and then reimplement it using C/C++ numerical libraries. Anyway, Matlab loops have been slow back in the nineties, they got much faster in recent versions of Matlab.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that function `B =`[`blockproc`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/blockproc.html)`(A, [M N], fun)` does exactly what you need. It applies function `fun` for every block of image `A` and then concatenates results. There are also options for reading image directly from file.